# How to convert/compile 64-bit python (2.7.4) as 32-bit python on linux?

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to use existing  tcl/expect (32 bit) lib in python (64 bit). It gives me an error when I try to invoke tkinter. So I am trying to find out whether there is any way to convert python to support 32 bit.

> _tkinter.TclError: couldn't load file "~/ActiveTcl/8.4.19.1.286040/lib/expect5.44.1.9/libexpect5.44.1.9.so": ~/ActiveTcl/8.4.19.1.286040/lib/expect5.44.1.9/libexpect5.44.1.9.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

If you are aware of the steps to fix this, please share with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need proper so files for proper OS. Cant use just like that.. You need 64 bit libexpect5.44.1.9.so file from 64 bit machine. and load it before executing your code. You can also bundle up 64 bit libexpect5.44.1.9.so using sdx binary and keep loading it at the time of invocation.